# Trying to validate USER ID

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate an USER ID for a form. The specific condition tests are as follows:

Rule #1 All 10 positions must be present

Rule #2 Position 5 must be a hyphen (-)

Rule #3 Position 1 to 4 must be numeric digits

Rule #4 Position 6 to 10 must be numeric digits
The following two rules (#5 and #6) should only be checked if rule 1 through rule 4 has passed the validation

Rule #5 The sum of the numbers to the left of the hyphen (-) must be greater than zero and the sum of the numbers to the right of the hyphen (-) must be greater than zero

Rule #6 The sum of the numbers to the right of the hyphen (-) must be (double plus 2) the sum of the numbers to the left of the hyphen (-)

You must provide a different message for the different error conditions

When I try and perform this validation, the form submits itself when it should display the proper error message and I am unsure as to why.

JavaScript function:

```
function validateUserId() {
   var value = document.getElementById("userId").value;
   if (value.length != 10) {
   errMessages += "User ID all 10 positions must be present";
 return errMessages;
  }
  if (value[4] != "-") {
errMessages +="User ID Position 5 must be a hyphen (-)" ;
return errMessages;
 }
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (isNaN(value[i]))  {
  errMessages += "User ID Position " + i + " must be a number" ;
  return errMessages;
  }
 }
 for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
  if (isNaN(value[i]))  {
  errMessages += "User ID Position " + i + " must be a number" ;
  }
 }
var lowsum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
lowsum += parseInt(value[i]);
}
 if (lowsum <= 0) {
errMessages += "User ID Sum of the first 4 numbers must be greater than 0" ;
 return errMessages;
 }
 var highsum = 0;
 for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
 highsum += parseInt(value[i]);
  }
  if (highsum <= 0) {
  errMessages += "User ID Sum of the last 5 numbers must be greater than 0"  ;
return errMessages;
 }
  if (highsum != (lowsum * 2) + 2) {
 errMessages += "User ID sum of the last 5 numbers must be the double plus of of the first 4 numbers" ;
return errMessages;
 }
return errMessages;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="label">Client ID </label>    
        <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" size="10" maxlength="10" >
```

Comment: How are you calling your validateUserId function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine. But you need to `return` only `false`. Change your code this way:

```js
function validateUserId() {
  var value = document.getElementById("userId").value;
  if (value.length != 10) {
    errMessages += "User ID all 10 positions must be present";
    alert(errMessages);
    return false;
  }
  if (value[4] != "-") {
    errMessages +="User ID Position 5 must be a hyphen (-)" ;
    alert(errMessages);
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (isNaN(value[i]))  {
      errMessages += "User ID Position " + i + " must be a number" ;
      alert(errMessages);
      return false;
    }
  }
  for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    if (isNaN(value[i]))  {
      errMessages += "User ID Position " + i + " must be a number" ;
    }
  }
  var lowsum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    lowsum += parseInt(value[i]);
  }
  if (lowsum <= 0) {
    errMessages += "User ID Sum of the first 4 numbers must be greater than 0" ;
    alert(errMessages);
    return false;
  }
  var highsum = 0;
  for (i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    highsum += parseInt(value[i]);
  }
  if (highsum <= 0) {
    errMessages += "User ID Sum of the last 5 numbers must be greater than 0"  ;
    alert(errMessages);
    return false;
  }
  if (highsum != (lowsum * 2) + 2) {
    errMessages += "User ID sum of the last 5 numbers must be the double plus of of the first 4 numbers" ;
    alert(errMessages);
    return false;
  }
  alert(errMessages);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateUserId()">
  <input id="userId" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```